# How to create a batch file in vba

Tags: vba, batch-file

I'm trying to create a batch file and then write the batch file here is my code:

```
Dim sr As System.IO.StreamWriter
If fso.FileExists(FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath & "\ServerStart.bat") Then
    fso.DeleteFile(FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath & "\ServerStart.bat")
    sr = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath & "\ServerStart.bat", True)
    sr.Write("java -Xms2048m -Xmx8048m -jar " & fso.GetFileName(file) & " nogui pause")
    sr.Close()
Else
    sr = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath & "\ServerStart.bat", True)
    sr.Write("java -Xms2048m -Xmx8048m -jar " & fso.GetFileName(file) & " nogui pause")
    sr.Close()
End If
```

Even though the text looks fine in notepad when I try to run the batch file I get this: '´╗┐java' is not recognized as an internal or external command.
So basically when I use streamwriter to edit the batch file it adds this: '´╗┐

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BOM unicode marker bytes written probably, use this method to write ISO-8859-1 ascii file: OpenTextFileWriter(file, append, encoding)
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms128024(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I'm still getting '´╗┐ in the start would you give me an example?

Comment: Figured out how to do it I added System.Text.Encoding.ASCII: 
sr = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath & "\ServerStart.bat", True, System.Text.Encondig.ASCII
Thanks.